# STEVAL-STWINKT1 Board: save ADC data to sd card

Tags: embedded, stm32, sd-card, sampling, adc

I am using STEVAL-STWINKT1 Board to capture ADC data to SD Card.
Please help me with this-

1. I am not sure if I can see the plot and FFT of my ADC signal on the Bluetooth App.
2. code to save ADC data to sd card (facing to get data on card)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If this is a "give me the code", question; then no.  What is the specific problem you have?  What has Bluetooth to do with this question? What is the sample rate? Variable latency of SD card writes will require some significant buffering, and probably block writes in some multiple of the sector size. YMMV.